# Use GPS with Google Maps API javascript

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, gps

I have developed a map and I would like to do GPS service like Google Maps APP. Is it possible? I couldn't find anything on this topic.

The idea is that the APP will direct me to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Geolocation:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
    console.log("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like that my APP direct me like Google Map APP. With voice :) @sebastiaan-mearadji